# Space of Tab symbol in LiteIDE

Tags: go, liteide

Can I adjust the space setting of tab symbol in LiteIDE. The space is different with other editors. I tried to find it but cannot find out how to adjust the space.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about setting of an editor and unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 3):

That would be because `go fmt` no longer authorize modifying tab width: see [revision 34dac78e0550](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=34dac78e0550), as discussed in [LiteIDE issue 125](https://github.com/visualfc/liteide/issues/125):

### `cmd/gofmt`: remove `-tabwidth` and `-tabs` flags

> Having these flags misleads people into thinking they're acceptable for code that "must be `gofmt`'d".
>
> If an organization wishes to use gofmt internally with different settings, they can fork `gofmt` trivially. But "`gofmt`" as used by the community with open source Go code should not
>   support these old knobs.

---

That being said, the editor itself still authorizes custom tab width since [20121228-ver-x151](https://github.com/visualfc/liteide/blob/master/liteidex/deploy/welcome/en/changes.md#20121228-ver-x151):

Go to **`View > Options > LiteEditor > File Types`**

[image: custom tab width]